# US Non Resident filing 1040NR - Should he declare ESPP sale in Canada during the tax period

Tags: united-states, taxes

I was non-resident of US in 2015. I Moved to US/california on 31-Dec-2015 on L1-B visa on last day of the year from Canada where I was resident. I have been in US only 30 days in last 3 years.

So I will be filing 1040NR.

I had sold ESPP and RSU last year while in Canada, before moving to US.
Do I need to include the sale transactions on the 1040NR? I will be including and paying capital gain/losses for them in Canadian taxes.
Appreciate your response